# How do I convert the certain column of RDD into integer type and save it as txt?

Tags: python, rdd, pyshark

For example, when I read a [csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Egedz.png) csv document and use rdd to transform it into a txt file, how do I choose the first columns and save it as the txt file?
It seems rdd do not have that special function to select the 1st column

Answer (score 0):

Plain `RDD`s don't have any schema, unless you imposed one: so the concept of column doesn't really apply.
You can try with

```
rdd[0]
```

and that will give you the data corresponding to the first column.